# EXCEL!! Multiple SUMIFS with multiple criterias

Tags: excel, sumifs

So I got a 2 tables, in table 1 cells look like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vt6ZxoE.jpg]

What I need is a formula that will sum the values out of Column A for each letter (even if they repeat themselves throughout different columns) and put them in a table like this bellow

[image]

So the end result should look like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5Op5ZcS.jpg]

Just please have in mind this is a table of a couple of hundreds rows and 10 columns

Thank you!

Comment: Is Sumif not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your value for H is incorrect and should really be 4, try this formula in Table2 Sumvalues Row 1 (A9 above)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[T1]:[T4]]=Table2[[#This Row],[LETTER]])*Table1[Value])
```